# ERROR: PayPal: Prop is required: payment

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, paypal

I am running into an issue that I do not completely understand. Following this demo from the PayPal developer site: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

I am running into the error in the title of this post.

Here are some code samples
Client side:
    payment: function () {

```
        // Make a call to the merchant server to set up the payment

        return paypal.request.post('My/api/call').then(function (res) {

            return res.token;
        });
    },
```

Server side (my/api/call)

```
var createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);

return createdPayment;
```

I am using the PayPal-NET-SDK to create these objects and return them to which PayPal seems to be OK with until the response is returned. The demo code from PayPal, I think, implies that a payment object is returned. Which is what I am returning from the server (PayPal gives it an ID, a token, etc from the api call), granted the property name of the token is different. Does anyone have any insight into what may be going on?

Thanks

EDIT: Asa per request here is the payment.Create method

```
/// <summary>
    /// Creates and processes a payment. In the JSON request body, include a `payment` object with the intent, payer, and transactions. For PayPal payments, include redirect URLs in the `payment` object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="apiContext">APIContext used for the API call.</param>
    /// <returns>Payment</returns>
    public Payment Create(APIContext apiContext)
    {
        return Payment.Create(apiContext, this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates (and processes) a new Payment Resource.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="apiContext">APIContext used for the API call.</param>
    /// <param name="payment">Payment object to be used in creating the PayPal resource.</param>
    /// <returns>Payment</returns>
    public static Payment Create(APIContext apiContext, Payment payment)
    {
        // Validate the arguments to be used in the request
        ArgumentValidator.ValidateAndSetupAPIContext(apiContext);

        // Configure and send the request
        var resourcePath = "v1/payments/payment";
        var resource = PayPalResource.ConfigureAndExecute<Payment>(apiContext, HttpMethod.POST, resourcePath, payment.ConvertToJson());
        resource.token = resource.GetTokenFromApprovalUrl();
        return resource;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `payment.Create` method?

Comment: Shared the code in OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return either the EC-XXXXXXX token or the PAY-XXXXXX id, as a string, not the entire payment object.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but  I then get the error: Prop is not of type string: payment

Comment: Where does the demo state that? Can you share the new code you're using? It definitely expects a string -- are you console logging to make sure the string is populated before you return it?

Comment: I misinterpreted 'Make a call to the merchant server to set up the payment', it does seem that the code expects an object with a property 'payToken'. Nonetheless, I have tried just returning the string. See error in comment above. Thanks for the time

Comment: I just retried what you suggested and it worked fine. There may have been something cached on my page, my apologies. Thanks for the help!